# Nested JSON and HyperlinkedModelSerializer problem

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I'm working on a tweet App. I have 2 main models : Tweets and Comments. I'm using HyperlinkedModelSerializer to get absolute url for my comments instances with the "url" added in the field. But when It comes to display the comments inside my tweet JSON format, i have this error :

```
`HyperlinkedIdentityField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer.
```

This error is gone when I remove the url from the field. 
Here is my Comment Model :

```
class CommentManager(models.Manager):
def filter_by_instance(self, instance):
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
    obj_id = instance.id
    qs = super(CommentManager, self).filter(content_type=content_type, object_id=obj_id)
    return qs


class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
    )
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    datestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = CommentManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.content[:30])

    def save(self):
        self.object_id = self.parent.id
        super(Comment, self).save()

    def children(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(parent=self)

    @property
    def is_parent(self):
        if self.parent is None:
            return False
        return True
```

Here is my comment serializer  :

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

children = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
datestamp = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_datestamp(self, obj):
    return obj.datestamp.date()

def get_children(self, obj):
    qs = obj.children()
    return ChildrenCommentSerializer(qs, many=True).data

class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = [
        "url",
        "datestamp",
        "content",
        "is_parent",
        "object_id",
        "children"
    ]


class ChildrenCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            "content"
        ]
```

And finally my tweet serializer :

```
class TweetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="username", queryset=User.objects.all())
comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
datestamp = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_datestamp(self, obj):
    return obj.datestamp.date()

def get_comments(self, obj):
    qs =  Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(obj)
    print()
    print()
    print(CommentSerializer(qs, many=True))
    print()
    print()
    return CommentSerializer(qs, many=True).data

class Meta:
    model = Tweet
    fields = ["datestamp", "id", "content", "author", "nb_likes", "nb_comments", "slug", "comments"  ]

def to_representation(self, obj):
    representation = super().to_representation(obj)
    if obj.nb_likes > 50:
        representation['super_popular'] = True
    return representation
```

I do not understand how and where in the code i should add the "context={'request': request}"

Comment: in `TweetSerializer`

Comment: when **instantiating** your `CommentSerializer`: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#absolute-and-relative-urls

Comment: it return me name 'request' is not defined. and when i add request to my get_comments method, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place it when instantiating the serializer

```
class ViewExample(APIView):

  def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
    listexample = Example.objects.all()
    serializer = ExampleSerializer(listexample, many=True, context={'request':request})
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Omg yhea that sounds obvious right now ! Thank you so much ! Do you know why we need to add that context

Comment: When instantiating a HyperlinkedModelSerializer you must include the current request in the serializer context, Doing so will ensure that the hyperlinks can include an appropriate hostname, so that the resulting representation uses fully qualified URLs. This explanation was taken from https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/.
This documentation is very complete.